# privoxy blocks all traffic on browser configured to use 127.0.0.1:8118 proxy url

Tags: debian, privoxy, lmde

I'm in the process of distro hopping and in the past configuring privoxy has been a simple task.  This time I am using LMDE 201403 (essentially a debian wheezy system).  I've installed and started privoxy after editing the config file at /etc/privoxy/config. I added a few debug lines:

```
debug     1 # Log the destination for each request Privoxy let through. See also debug 1024.
debug  1024 # Actions that are applied to all sites and maybe overruled later on.
debug  4096 # Startup banner and warnings
debug  8192 # Non-fatal errors
```

I also added a couple of forward rules:

```
forward                 champ/ .
forward                 192.168.2.*/ .
```

but I've also tried running privoxy with theses lines commented. Same result.

I'm not getting anything useful in the logs except:

```
2014-07-10 20:05:47.098 7f080a637700 Info: Privoxy version 3.0.21
2014-07-10 20:05:47.098 7f080a637700 Info: Program name: /usr/sbin/privoxy
2014-07-10 20:05:47.098 7f080a637700 Info: Loading filter file: /etc/privoxy/default.filter
2014-07-10 20:05:47.117 7f080a637700 Info: Loading filter file: /etc/privoxy/user.filter
2014-07-10 20:05:47.122 7f080a637700 Info: Loading actions file: /etc/privoxy/match-all.action
2014-07-10 20:05:47.122 7f080a637700 Info: Loading actions file: /etc/privoxy/default.action
2014-07-10 20:05:47.146 7f080a637700 Info: Loading actions file: /etc/privoxy/user.action
2014-07-10 20:05:47.148 7f080a637700 Info: Listening on port 8118 on IP address localhost
```

In my browser configured to use the proxy url 127.0.0.1:8118 all traffic is blocked.  I cannot reach the privoxy configuration page at either  http://config.privoxy.org/ or http://p.p/

What other debug codes would help determine what is blocking all traffic?  Any ideas what might be causing this blockage?